# Firestore class with func and return data

Tags: ios, swift, class, google-cloud-firestore

How i can create class which I can use for load data from Firestore and use him in all my classes?

Now I have this class, but his `Result of call to ... unused`:

```
import Foundation
import Firebase

class FSLoadData {

    static var shared = FSLoadData()

    private func firestore(_ collection: String) -> CollectionReference {
        let firestore = Firestore.firestore().collection(collection)
        return firestore
    }

    func loadBookingData(_ id: String,
                     bookData: PhotoBooking?) -> PhotoBooking? {
        var newBook = bookData
        firestore(FSCollections.photoBooking).document(id).getDocument { (snapshot, error) in
            if let err = error {
                print(err.localizedDescription)
            } else {
                if let snap = snapshot, snap.exists {
                    if let book = PhotoBooking(dictionary: snap.data()!, id: snap.documentID) {
                        newBook = book
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return newBook
    }
}
```

And I try to use this `class` in other classes in `viewWillApear`

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(true)
    FSLoadData.shared.loadBookingData(id, bookData: moreDetailBooking)
}
```

But I get error:

> Result of call to ... unused

Comment: it's better to load the data inside `viewDidLoad` it's more earlier and called once

Comment: Please post complete error messages. Don’t leave out the important details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a completion

```
func loadBookingData(_ id: String,
                 completion:@escaping(PhotoBooking?) -> ()) { 

    firestore(FSCollections.photoBooking).document(id).getDocument { (snapshot, error) in
        if let err = error {
            print(err.localizedDescription)
            completion(nil)
        } else {
            if let snap = snapshot, snap.exists {
                if let book = PhotoBooking(dictionary: snap.data()!, id: snap.documentID) {
                   completion(book)
                }
                else {
                   completion(nil)
                }
            }
            else {
                 completion(nil)
             }
        }
    } 
}
```

---

Call

```
loadBookingData("someValue") { data in 
    if let res = data {
      print(res)
    }
}
```